# how to create refFromURL with admin privilege on cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I want to have a reference to an image using its http URL when firestore update cloud function triggered so that i can take the url from `change` provide by `onUpdate()` function and use it to get a reference to the image on firebase storage and delete it.

Comment: I think you don't need the URL of the file to do what you want to do. Normally you would just need the bucket and file names. Do you want to use the URL to identify the file because your users don't know any other identifier?? In addition, are you speaking about the "storage location URL" or about a "download URL" for the file?

Comment: I'm talking about Http download URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to delete a file stored in Cloud Storage for Firebase from a Cloud Function you will need to create a `File` object based on:

1. The Bucket instance this file is attached to;
2. The name of the file,

and then call the `delete()` method

as detailed in the Node.js library documentation https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/File.

Here is an example of code from the documentation:

```
const storage = new Storage();
const bucketName = 'Name of a bucket, e.g. my-bucket';
const filename = 'File to delete, e.g. file.txt';

// Deletes the file from the bucket
storage
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .file(filename)
  .delete()
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`gs://${bucketName}/${filename} deleted.`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

From your question, I understand that your app clients don't have the bucket and file names as such and only have a download URL (probably generated through [getDownloadURL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL) if it is a web app, or the similar method for other SDKs).

So the challenge is to derive the bucket and file names from a download URL.

If you look at the format of a download URL you will find that it is composed as follows:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<your-project-id>.appspot.com/o/<your-bucket-name>%2F<your-file-name>?alt=media&token=<a-token-string>
```

So you just need to use a set of Javascript methods like `indexOf()`, `substring()` and/or `slice()` to extract the bucket and file names from the download URL.

Based on the above, your Cloud Function code could then look like:

```
const storage = new Storage();

.....

exports.deleteStorageFile = functions.firestore
    .document('deletionRequests/{requestId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      const newValue = change.after.data();
      const downloadUrl = newValue.downloadUrl;

      // extract the bucket and file names, for example through two dedicated Javascript functions
      const fileBucket = getFileBucket(downloadUrl);
      const fileName = getFileName(downloadUrl);

      return storage
        .bucket(fileBucket)
        .file(fileName)
        .delete()

    });
```

Comment: I'm currently doing it like this ,I just wanted to see if there is more efficient way that could create reference with ease . So weird that Firebase engineers have not made api for doing this yet .Anyways thanks a lot @Renaud Tarnec